# cause of app cache deletion

Tags: android, caching, notifications

I have a quick question.

What can be the cause of the cache deletion of the app?

Let's just say I'm receiving a notification and opening the app and all my cache removed, I couldn't even see saved accounts and application acts like it is installed the first time.

Comment: cache persist internal app data, whenever cache is clear or delete its cleared  database as well as sharedpref data.

Comment: Are you sure you are preforming saving correctly? And without code we could just keep guessing

Comment: Sorry if I described the situation badly, I'm persisting them on sharedprefs and works perfectly, but client came to me with this problem, all I'm asking the situations that cause this problem like memory?